# How to Add IField Object in Crystal Report Manually (Without Wizard Intervention)

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, crystal-reports, reporting

I need help about creating a crystal report. Yeah, I can make a crystal report using the wizard via Visual Studio 2008 but it is not my goal because I am trying to implement a report application that doesn't need to be configure in the future in terms of database connectivity. What the wizard is doing was, it ask for a datasource via wizard and if I am going to change the database I am going to the code again to update the datasource. I just want the datasource to be in a config file and then I will call it.

Here is my code for now but it seems not working. I need to add Ifield Object manually without using the heck wizard of crystal reports. I've tried to googled it for days but no exact answer can resolve my problem, can anyone pleas help me? Thanks!

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
        ServiceReference.WebServiceSoapClient service = new ServiceReference.WebServiceSoapClient();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lblString.Text = connectionString;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds = (service.getAllUsers());

            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

            CrystalReport1 reportCR = new CrystalReport1();
            reportCR.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);

         // crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportCR;

          //crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();

        }
```

Comment: Did you try using xml as you're report source. That way you could update xml when you'll need it updated,

Comment: i don't want it to be in an xml, i preferto use web service